# I can't find the Oython code of this problem in the given image?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Find the Python code for this problem.

[image]

```
n = int(input())
result = ''
for i in range(1,n):
    result += str(i)
    print(result)
```

Comment: Dont use image. Use text and explain your question

Comment: So what have you tried?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please note this site isn't intended for solving homework for users. If you could edit your question to show any effort that you've put into solving the question we may help.

Comment: No this is not my intention. I tried many but I couldn't find the correct code. And it is not homework but it is Hackerrank's question and I couldn't solve it. I tried a lot but I didn't get the correct logic.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account. [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) applies here. We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately specify the problem. We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you specified.

Answer (score 1):

Also, you can use `join` method:

```py
n = int(input())

print(''.join([str(number) for number in range(1, n + 1)]))
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems with your code:

- the upper limit of `range` is exclusive, thus in order to include `n`, you have to use the upper bound `n+1`
- your are printing the `result` in each step of the loop, instead of just once after the loop (remember that in Python indentation matters)

If you fix those two problems, your code should work fine.